# CHECK_GEARMAN CRITICAL - function 'BulkEmail' is not registered in the server

Tags: linux, bash, nagios, gearman

I am using the nagios to monitor gearman and getting error "CRITICAL - function 'xxx' is not registered in the server"

Script that nagios execute to check the gearman is like

```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl

# taken from: gearmand-0.24/libgearman-server/server.c:974
# function->function_name, function->job_total,
# function->job_running, function->worker_count);
#
# this code give following result with gearadmin --status
#
# FunctionName                job_total job_running  worker_count
# AdsUpdateCountersFunction       0           0           4

use strict;
use warnings;

use Nagios::Plugin;

my $VERSION="0.2.1";
my $np;

$np = Nagios::Plugin->new(usage => "Usage: %s -f|--flist <func1[:threshold1],..,funcN[:thresholdN]> [--host|-H <host>] [--port|-p <port>] [ -c|--critworkers=<threshold> ] [ -w|--warnworkers=<threshold>] [-?|--usage] [-V|--version] [-h|--help] [-v|--verbose] [-t|--timeout=<timeout>]",
                          version => $VERSION,
                          blurb => 'This plugin checks a gearman job server, expecting that every function in function-list arg is registered by at least one worker, and expecting that job_total is not too much high.',
                          license => "Brought to you AS IS, WITHOUT WARRANTY, under GPL. (C) Remi Paulmier <remi.paulmier\@gmail.com>",
                          shortname => "CHECK_GEARMAN",
                         );

$np->add_arg(spec => 'flist|f=s',
             help => q(Check for the functions listed in STRING, separated by comma. If optional threshold is given (separated by :), check that waiting jobs for this particular function are not exceeding that value),
             required => 1,
            );
$np->add_arg(spec => 'host|H=s',
             help => q(Check the host indicated in STRING),
             required => 0,
             default => 'localhost',
            );

$np->add_arg(spec => 'port|p=i',
             help => q(Use the TCP port indicated in INTEGER),
             required => 0,
             default => 4730,
            );

$np->add_arg(spec => 'critworkers|c=i',
             help => q(Exit with CRITICAL status if fewer than INTEGER workers have registered a particular function),
             required => 0,
             default => 1,
            );

$np->add_arg(spec => 'warnworkers|w=i',
             help => q(Exit with WARNING status if fewer than INTEGER workers have registered a particular function),
             required => 0,
             default => 4,
            );

$np->getopts;
my $ng = $np->opts;

# manage timeout
alarm $ng->timeout;

my $runtime = {'status' => OK,
               'message' => "Everything OK",
              };

# host & port
my $host = $ng->get('host');
my $port = $ng->get('port');

# verbosity
my $verbose = $ng->get('verbose');# look for gearadmin, use nc if not found
my @paths = grep { -x "$_/gearadmin" } split /:/, $ENV{PATH};
my $cmd = "gearadmin --status -h $host -p $port";
if (@paths == 0) {
        print STDERR "gearadmin not found, using nc\n" if ($verbose != 0);
#       $cmd = "echo status | nc -w 1 $host $port";
        $cmd = "echo status | nc -i 1 -w 1 $host $port";
}

foreach (`$cmd 2>/dev/null | grep -v '^\\.'`) {
        chomp;

        my ($fname, $job_total, $job_running, $worker_count) =
          split /[[:space:]]+/;

        $runtime->{'funcs'}{"$fname"} = {job_total => $job_total,
                                         job_running => $job_running,
                                         worker_count => $worker_count };
        # print "$fname : $runtime->{'funcs'}{\"$fname\"}{'worker_count'}\n";
}

# get function list
my @flist = split /,/, $ng->get('flist');

foreach (@flist) {

        my ($fname, $fthreshold);

        if (/\:/) {
                ($fname, $fthreshold) = split /:/;
        } else {
                ($fname, $fthreshold) = ($_, -1);
        }

#       print "defined for $fname: $runtime->{'funcs'}{\"$fname\"}{'worker_count'}\n";

#       if (defined($runtime->{'funcs'}{"$fname"})) {
#               print "$fname is defined\n";
#       } else {
#               print "$fname is NOT defined\n";
#       }

        if (!defined($runtime->{'funcs'}{"$fname"}) &&
            $runtime->{'status'} <= CRITICAL) {

                ($runtime->{'status'}, $runtime->{'message'}) =
                  (CRITICAL, "function '$fname' is not registered in the server");
        } else {
                if ($runtime->{'funcs'}{"$fname"}{'worker_count'} <
                    $ng->get('critworkers') && $runtime->{'status'} <= CRITICAL) {

                        ($runtime->{'status'}, $runtime->{'message'}) =
                          (CRITICAL,
                           "less than " .$ng->get('critworkers').
                           " workers were found having function '$fname' registered.");
                }

                if ($runtime->{'funcs'}{"$fname"}{'worker_count'} <
                    $ng->get('warnworkers') && $runtime->{'status'} <= WARNING) {

                        ($runtime->{'status'}, $runtime->{'message'}) =
                          (WARNING,
                           "less than " .$ng->get('warnworkers').
                           " workers were found having function '$fname' registered.");
                }

                if ($runtime->{'funcs'}{"$fname"}{'job_total'} > $fthreshold
                    && $fthreshold != -1 && $runtime->{'status'}<=WARNING) {

                        ($runtime->{'status'}, $runtime->{'message'}) =
                          (WARNING,
                           $runtime->{'funcs'}{"$fname"}{'job_total'}.
                           " jobs for $fname exceeds threshold $fthreshold");
                }
        }
}

$np->nagios_exit($runtime->{'status'}, $runtime->{'message'});
```

When the script is executed simply by command line it says "everything ok"

But in nagios it shows error "CRITICAL - function 'xxx' is not registered in the server"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

After spending long time on this, finally got the answer all that have to do is.

yum install nc

nc is what that was missing from the system.

With Regards,
Bankat Vikhe

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to say but it could be related to your script not being executable as [embedded Perl](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/embeddedperl.html).

Try with `# nagios: -epn` at the beginning of the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# nagios: -epn

use strict;
use warnings;
```

Be sure to check all the hints in the [*Perl Plugins*](https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html#PERLPLUGIN) section of the [*Nagios Plugin Development Guidelines*](https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/guidelines.html)

Comment: Matteo, thanks for the response but this did not help as error remains same.